# Recreating Cookies on another Domain

Tags: cookies, cross-domain, session-cookies

I have a site on A.com and an iframe on B.com which reads info from A.com. I realize that there is some problems with third party cookies, iframes and P3P - particularly in Safari [my problem]

Is it possible to instead,  use AJAX or a hidden iFrame to pass the cookie information from A.com to B.com which will then "recreate" another cookie with the same information on the iframe in B.com.

Comment: The frame on B.com does it read data from A.com with a background request or does the frame actually go to A.com?

Comment: yeah sorry - the iframe on B.com reads data from a.com - i.e. at the moment using third party cookies - so the third party cookie appears in the iframe and we have a cookie so the user remains logged in - but they don't work in safari.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iFrames and Cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948130/iframes-and-cookies)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.